# Using NodeJS for our API, how to control what HTTP status codes are sent from Hapi?

Tags: hapi.js

We are using Hapi for our simple API. We have out own auth system, so if a user calls our API, but they are not authenticated, I want to send back a 401 HTTP status code.

I saw this post:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-set-response-status-code

which offers this example:

```
  handler: function (request, reply) {
     var data = { key: 'value' }
    reply(data).code(201)
  }
```

So I started adding in response codes, including codes for our exceptions:

```
        DB.knex.raw(query).then(function(result) {
                    var dataJson = [];
                    var responseJson = {};

                    for(var i in result[0]) {

                        dataJson.push({
            "name": result[0][i]["name"],
            "profile_id": result[0][i]["profile_id"],
            "profile_type": result[0][i]["profile_type"],
            "profile_classification": result[0][i]["profile_classification"],
            "permalink": result[0][i]["permalink"],
            "location": result[0][i]["location"],
            });                 
                    }

                    responseJson["data"] = dataJson;
                    reply(responseJson).code(200);
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.error(e);
            reply(e).code(500);
        });
```

but I immediately got this error:

```
TypeError: query.then(...).catch(...).code is not a function
```

So... I guess I can't do this. I am confused by the error, since I am not calling ".code()" on the "catch", I am calling it on the reply().

We are using Boom, does that override the advice in the article? The article talks about Boom, but does not make clear that Boom overrides the earlier advice.

Comment: can you give us your query for knex? and what is DB.knex? Knex instance

Comment: The query has not changed in months, so it seems unlikely to be a source of problems?

Comment: Using `Boom` you may try to replace your `reply(e).code(500);` (which reads correctly to my eyes though) by `reply(Boom.badImplementation(""+e));` which is expected to reply a 500 with the message contained in `e` (and makes sure `e` is casted to a string).
However, are you certain this `TypeError` comes from this line? It indeed seems really weird...

Comment: This was the line number given in the stacktrace. I'll try your idea.

Comment: Maybe something about the wrong kind of promise?